# PHP array(Undefined offset)

Tags: php, arrays, tags, undefined

here's something that confuse me, the code is the same but this got this undefined offset, and here's the code :

```
<?php
$day = array("Sunday"    => "Minggu",
               "Monday"    => "Senin",
               "Tuesday"   => "Selasa",
               "Wednesday" => "Rabu",
               "Thursday"  => "Kamis",
               "Friday"    => "Jumat",
               "Saturday"  => "Sabtu");
$elemen = date(1);
echo("Today is : $day[$elemen]");
```

?>

the code is the same on my friend but mine show this undefined offset, but him show Today is bla bla without any error.
looking forward for the hint.
thanks i really appreciate it..

Comment: use date(l) not 1. Its "L".

Comment: No response from peoples asking question, even after asking. frustrating. deleting my answer

Answer (score 1):

[`date`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) accepts a format string, which `1` isn't. I'm guessing you tried to use the format to retrieve today's name, which would be `'l'` (a lower case L):

```
$elemen = date('l');
```

Comment: It again gives:-Notice: Use of undefined constant l - assumed 'l' in your php file path  on line 9
Today is : Senin

Comment: @anantkumarsingh got caught up explaining the formatting I completely forgot about quoting the `'l'`. Fixed, see my edited answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
(!empty($day[sunday]))
```

This check would possibly solve your problem